# How to set 2 styles to same value in same line?

Tags: css

Is there an easy way to write `left:15%;right:15%` as `left,right:15%` or something similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us some context where `left` and `right` are being used?

Comment: provide more info pls

Answer (score 0):

No, in pure CSS, it’s impossible to combine multiple properties in a single declaration.

But using a CSS preprocessor like [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) (e. g. using a PHP-powered implementation like [scssphp](https://github.com/leafo/scssphp/)), you could write a mixin like this:

```
@mixin left-right($value) {
    left: $value;
    right: $value;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
.example {
    @include left-right(15%);
}
```

which would produce the following CSS:

```
.example {
    left: 15%;
    right: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently not, but some ways to merge them in a shorthand property have been proposed.

> But for `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` we were thinking of using `offset` as
>   the prefix for the logical properties (and hence `offset` as the
>   shorthand that sets all of them)
>   — [fantasai](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0431.html)

> I like the idea, but `offset` seems less than ideal. What if
>   'position' was the shorthand and the prefix? Like `position: absolute 0 auto 0 0`?
>   — [Brad Kemper](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0450.html)

> And actually, by sheer coincidence, I happened to stumble across a
>   PostCSS plugin called "Short", which used this syntax. 
>   https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-short/blob/master/README.md
>   — [Brad Kemper](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0455.html)

But if you only want to avoid repeating the same value, you can use CSS variables:

```css
div {
  --side: 15%;
  left: var(--side);
  right: var(--side);
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It says no support for IE or Edge with CSS variables http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables